# Logstash consuming from Kafka on schedule

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to have a kafka input that consumes from kafka on periods. I.E., every 5 minutes consume until consumer group lag is 0, and then start again in the next 5 minute interval. The reason for this is that I have two pipelines both consuming the same topic that could introduce a race condition if I do not have one of them running at a slower cadence.

Is this possible, or would I need to dump the events into a temporary index and then have my logstash consume from that index every 5 minutes instead?

I found this post asking for exactly what I am looking for but it has 0 replies: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-schedule-logstash-pipelibe-to-consume-kafka-input-logs-every-15min/255320

Comment: That's not how Kafka is supposed to work.